# What is a bent star-shaped washer found in shower door handle called?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower

My shower door handle became loose and when I pulled it off, there was this bent washer-like bit of metal. There is another one inside the tube of the door handle. (See photos) I googled "star washer" and "lock washer" but none of the results look like this. It looks like it was designed to be bent during installation. **Does anyone know what this piece is called?** Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Leaving this as a comment, since that washer was made specifically to hold that particular brand of handle in place. Seeing the set screw in the other half that is still mounted n the door, that half, is what is set in place last. The part that is now separate was not supposed to come apart at all, and when it is together as it should be is simply inserted through the holes in the glass door, where there is a reverse tapered shaft which the set screw visible in the picture, when tightened on the taper, snugs the handle in place. My Idea would be to (continued)

Comment: disassemble the separate components of the side that fell apart, see if there is a way that the threaded section on the faulty half is made so it squeezes the washer in question so it will spread automatically when it is tightened to grip the inside of the handle that fell off. If that does as I hope, reassemble the handle side that fell apart, slip it through the glass door with the plastic washers in the right places and reset the handle with the set screw.  There may even be a machined lip on the inside of the handle for the washer to grip into.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [*tubing insert*](https://www.google.com/search?q=round%20tubing%20insert&tbm=isch). They can be washers, spacers, or threaded (like a nut). Yours is round, but you'll also find such [inserts for square tubing](https://www.google.com/search?q=square%20tubing%20insert&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 1):

That's a piece of proprietary hardware. Internally the manufacturer may have a name for it, but you're not going to find a local supplier (unless you happen to live in the manufacturer's city).